# Get result of a MySQL query after PHP script timeout

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

I have a PHP UI for running SQL queries. In case the script times out, the result won't be displayed, but the query is still running. How can I the result later? One thing that comes on my mind is using

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'out.txt'
```

Are there any other ways? This one is useful only if you have full control of the server.

UPDATE: Let's assume it's not possible to increase timeout of the PHP script.

Comment: increase the timeout setting for the script?

Comment: You can either use VIEW http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp or INSERT INTO SELECThttp://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp